# best way to replace an eval( "new object()" )

Tags: javascript, eval, draw2d-js

I m looking for the best way to replace eval( "new object();" )

The ugly source :

```
    //var type = window.$(droppedDomNode).data("shape");
    var type = "sankey.shape.Start";

    var figure = eval("new "+type+"();");
    
    // create a command for the undo/redo support
    var command = new draw2d.command.CommandAdd(this, figure, x, y);
```

The eval create a new sankey.shape.Start object.

I'm looking for best solution to replace this kind of code.

Thanks

Comment: Where does `sankey` come from? Is that an import or a global variable?

Comment: I drag and drop textual value from a list of item.

Comment: I mean, where is `sankey` defined in your code, do you know that?

Comment: sandkey is a global variable.

Comment: Any way with Object.create("sankey.shape.Start")  or a wrong solution ?

Comment: That doesn't work, the syntax would be Object.create(sankey.shape.Start.prototype)` (without double quotes)

Answer (score 5):

I'd build an object (mapping) of constructor functions.

```
const constructors = {
  "sankey.shape.Start": () => new sankey.shape.Start(),
  // etc... (this could be built programmatically)
};
```

Then,

```
const figure = constructors[type]();
```

Comment: Or `const constructors = { "sankey.shape.Start": sankey.shape.Start }; new constructors[type];`.

Comment: I think, I need protect the object creation . What happend if I wish create "sankey.shape.badobject"

Comment: You'd get a "undefined is not callable", since that key isn't in the mapping.

Answer (score 1):

You can split it and walk up the path from window if it is global

```js
var foo = {
  bar: {
    world: 'baz',
  }
}

const getIt = (str, start = window) => {
  return str.split(/\./).reduce((o, k) => o[k], start);
}


const x = "foo.bar.world";
console.log(getIt(x))
```